# How to insert HTML elements into DOM with Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble finding a good way to do this. What I want to do is when I go to a certain page, I want a button to appear and when you click it, it displays the first element of some array, and the next with each click.

I could do this in HTML, but how can I do this when my content script is only JS? I've done and seen other answers where they just create an element, append some nodes as a child like this in the contentscript.js

```
let nodeOne = document.querySelector('div');
let para = document.createElement('p')
para.innerText = 'hi'
nodeOne.appendChild(para)
```

but it seems inefficient and hard to manage if stuff is changing on the page (with each button press). Is there a way to write HTML code and inject it into the DOM from the contentscript.js?

Comment: Technically this is actually efficient. To reduce the boilerplate though you can use innerHTML, or jQuery or a virtual DOM framework and write the markup in JSX/Vue/whatever. The important thing is that you need to attach the listeners inside the content script, not as inline text inside html. You can also add an iframe and point it to an html page in your extension exposed via `web_accessible_resources`, look for demos/tutorials for this keyword.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank u sir

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi this is an old thread, but you mentioned using innerHTML and I had a question. I made a div and did something like this in the contentScript

`foo.innerHTML = \`<div>hi<div>\``

and appended it. Is it bad practice to use template literals or should I just continue doing the DOM API js method from the original post?

Comment: It's perfectly fine but if you ever going to post on Firefox extension gallery they won't accept it even with a literal string because they think it's easier to forbid the feature entirely than to investigate whether your innerHTML can come from an untrusted source so it could perform an XSS attack. If you need more info, it might be better to ask a new question.